# Issue with Hibernate EHCache program

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am learning how to configure Hibernate with EHCache but facing some issues with it.

I have below details in my `hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hib</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
        <mapping class="cache.three.Department"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is my `ehcache.xml` file:

```
<cache
    name="com.examples.domain.Country"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>
```

I am using `Hibernate-4.3.8` version. Now when I run my program just to create a SessionFactory using this configuration I am getting below exception:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at example.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at example.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at example.MyApp.storeData(MyApp.java:51)
    at example.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at example.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from file:/home/Hibernate/bin/ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:8: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "maxElementsInMemory".
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    ... 9 more
```

Please tell me know where I am making mistake in this configuration?

**Update:**

Replacing `maxElementsInMemory` with `maxEntriesLocalHeap` in ehcache.xml file is throwing below error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: null:8: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalHeap".
```

Comment: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "maxElementsInMemory". Which version of ehcache are you using?

Comment: @Marvin, Yes I can see that, but what is the correct way of configuring it, I am not able to get that.

Comment: Also a classpath problem, You have not  deployed the hibernate jars to your web-inf folder

Comment: Is your ehcache.xml file really at: /home/Hibetnate/bin/ehcache.xml notice Hibetnate vs. Hibernate

Comment: @user3181365: Looks as if it was intended to be replaced with "maxEntriesLocalHeap" in recent versions of ehcache (cf. http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html#maxElementsInMemory%28int%29). Not sure about your version and whether there are still other issues, though.

Comment: @danplubell, that was typing mistake, I have corrected it now, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @Marvin, I tried replacing with `maxEntriesLocalHeap`, again I am facing similar issue. I have updated my post with error details, please see.

Comment: I'm guessing there might be an incorrect version of ehcache on your classpath which conflicts with what hibernate expects (notice the different exception class - one is a SAXException, one comes from hibernate).

Comment: @Marvin, I have only `Hibernate 4.3.8` version Jar files, just now verified the complete list of Jars in my classpath. I am not sure where I am making mistake. Thank you for quick response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ehcache.xml file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>

 <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200" />    

<cache
    name="com.examples.domain.Country"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>
</ehcache>
```

It should start with `ehcache` tag and also you need to declare a `defaultCache` in it.